# Possible to have registered or unregistered RAM on same host?

Tags: memory, hardware, hp

When looking for refurbished HP ram for a DL360p with an Intel Xeon 2603v2 the following comes up.

There is already a registered Samsung and registered HP ram in the server, but it passes memtest86.

The support for the host have expired so I am using it just for testing software and are therefore temped to just go with the cheapest solution. In this case it is to add unregistered memory.

It is of course not best practice to mix ram brands and speed, but it works, so the question is:

**Question**

Would unregistered ram work in a host with all registered ram?

Registered DIMMs

- 713985-B21    HP 16GB (1x16GB) Dual Rank x4 PC3L-12800R (DDR3-1600) Registered CAS-11 Low Voltage Memory Kit
- 713985-S21    HP 16GB (1x16GB) Dual Rank x4 PC3L-12800R (DDR3-1600) Registered CAS-11 LP Memory Kit/S-Buy
- 708641-B21    HP 16GB (1x16GB) Dual Rank x4 PC3-14900R (DDR3-1866) Registered CAS-13 Memory Kit
- 708641-S21    HP 16GB (1x16GB) Dual Rank x4 PC3-14900R (DDR3-1866) Registered CAS-13 Memory Kit/S-Buy

Unbuffered with EEC Dimms

- 647901-B21 HP 16GB (1x16GB) Dual Rank x4 PC3L-10600R (DDR3-1333) Registered CAS-9 Low Voltage Memory Kit
- 647901-S21 HP 16GB (1x16GB) Dual Rank x4 PC3L-10600R (DDR3-1333) Registered CAS-9 Low Voltage Memory Kit/S-Buy
- 672631-B21 HP 16GB (1x16GB) Dual Rank x4 PC3-12800R (DDR3-1600) Registered CAS-11 Memory Kit
- 672631-S21 HP 16GB (1x16GB) Dual Rank x4 PC3-12800R (DDR3-1600) Registered CAS-11 Memory Kit S-Buy

Comment: If you managed to run memtest86, you can certainly find out what kind of RAM it is.

Comment: Now updated OP. Everything were registered, so I changed the question as well to be general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very unlikely that it will work. Not even all mainboards have support for registered/buffered memory, so a mix of the two is highly unsupported and it is not clear how the memory controller should handle some of the memory having a buffer (one cycle behind) and some not.

If you have registered/buffered then stay with that.